# Nested BlockchainBlockData fail

Tags: import, functional-style, cryptography

New 11.3 functions to query blockchains. In trying to build a block link by iterative lookup, this function works for several iterations then fails:

```
NestList[Query[BlockchainBlockData[#,BlockchainBase->"Bitcoin"]&]/* Query["PreviousBlockHash"],"00000000000000000038f324c04b678c85b5ee25ca8b36d8eef313e7e733293f",10]
```

> {00000000000000000038f324c04b678c85b5ee25ca8b36d8eef313e7e733293f,000000000000000000428a173468966d068f08f63f11c2d8db47d95ab861a32a,0000000000000000003b3bab092183a0fe6c33b6656f360c4118564478126a5b,00000000000000000004b9e238f822a7bdf4104ffcc8ef44c22bef468a47facd,Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed],Missing[Failed]}

even though individual queries work:

```
 BlockchainBlockData[
  "00000000000000000004b9e238f822a7bdf4104ffcc8ef44c22bef468a47facd", 
  BlockchainBase -> "Bitcoin"] // Query["PreviousBlockHash"]
```

> "0000000000000000003b6b67cb4c5db2edae01a630c3ff795148f2abce9dc223"

Similarly, plugging the result in gives a valid previous block hash etc.

Is it a resource bottleneck? I can't believe a Nest 10 levels deep would be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example accesses the blockchain too rapidly.  If we add the option `FailureAction->None` to the first query, we see the error message:

> BlockchainBlockData::btcrate: Rate limit exceeded for Bitcoin blockchain access.

Sniffing the network traffic, it would appear at time of writing that the service used is [blockcypher.com](https://www.blockcypher.com/).  The [API documentation](https://blockcypher.github.io/documentation/) states that the rate limit for an unregistered account is 5 requests/second and 600 requests/hour.

Accordingly, I was able to obtain a full result by inserting a 200ms delay before each request:

```
NestList[
   ( Pause[0.2]
   ; BlockchainBlockData[#, BlockchainBase -> "Bitcoin"]["PreviousBlockHash"]
   ) &
 , "00000000000000000038f324c04b678c85b5ee25ca8b36d8eef313e7e733293f"
 , 10
 ]

(*
{00000000000000000038f324c04b678c85b5ee25ca8b36d8eef313e7e733293f,
 000000000000000000428a173468966d068f08f63f11c2d8db47d95ab861a32a,
 0000000000000000003b3bab092183a0fe6c33b6656f360c4118564478126a5b,
 00000000000000000004b9e238f822a7bdf4104ffcc8ef44c22bef468a47facd,
 0000000000000000003b6b67cb4c5db2edae01a630c3ff795148f2abce9dc223,
 0000000000000000000506c50e99c65b74f2d00ef2344f8139a831fdb6f0be30,
 0000000000000000002f1d23de38e9a20f90f52524bbdb4451f0dbc49897ba22,
 000000000000000000190ac64c8c5a1a9acbf338d8435c0dcd74d41c0b031535,
 000000000000000000429f5fec52afdc16540ef5eda2d5a711a988db8041da46,
 0000000000000000003e0453ef04d9e17818ec3718d1811f1c0b295887828870,
 000000000000000000175173c6fe40dd7cd74612e7b844be0419d8eac86c8375}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the legwork.

Comment: That is correct. The functions introduced in v11.3 used an external API. The updated functions in v12 now use Wolfram resources and have a higher rate limit.