# BlockchainBlockData request limit exceeded

Tags: web-access, data-acquisition, api, cryptography

I'm trying to replicate this Blog entry on Bitcoin queries:

https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/05/25/sleuthing-darkside-crypto-ransom-payments-with-the-wolfram-language/

However, I don't get very far because the request limit (error 429) is exceed very fast:

```
$TimeZone = 0; $BlockchainBase = "Bitcoin";

In[2]:= currentblock = 683175;
blocktxs = 
  ParallelMap[{#, BlockchainTransactionData[#, "TotalInput"]} &, 
   BlockchainBlockData[currentblock, "TransactionList"]];
Select[blocktxs, Last[#] > Quantity[78, "Bitcoins"] &]

(kernel 2) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 1) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 6) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 2) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 3) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 6) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

(kernel 3) BlockchainTransactionData::errcon :  Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded
```

the next step completely fails:

```
In[3]:= BlockchainBlockData[683175, "TimeMined"]

During evaluation of In[6]:= BlockchainBlockData::errcon: Error connecting to server (StatusCode: 429): Limit exceeded

Out[3]= $Failed
```

I could find no info on what the limit is and if I can increase it.
Or can I add some delay to make this work?

Comment: I got the same issue on Windows 10, x64.

Comment: I didn't get the same issue on Windows 10 x64. Have you tried evaluating sequentially instead of in parallel? 

I did run this on 12.3 and had no errors. Sequentially or in parallel

Comment: @Shelton_swelton I tried the sequential `Map` and still get the same errors. Is this limited by the type of license? I'm on 12.2 Win10 x64.

Comment: Worked the first time I tried. Got the same error the second and subsequent times I tried. So there appears to be a limit, but I could not find it documented anywhere. I am on `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)`.

Comment: I get this error while disconnected from the Wolfram Cloud (`CloudDisconnect[]`), but not while connected (`CloudConnect[]`). I suspect whatever server these functions talk to enforces a stricter rate limit for unauthenticated users. Since the code is parallelized, one might also have to ensure Preferences > Parallel > Forward Cloud Credentials is enabled.

Comment: @JesseFriedman You are correct, that seems to be the issue! I can confirm that it works after connecting. I'd still be interested in the request limit.

Comment: Tried `CloudConnect[]`, enabling Forward Cloud Credentials, quitting and restarting. Get the error just executing `BlockchainBlockData[683175, "TransactionList"]`.

Comment: similar: [Nested BlockchainBlockData fail](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170689/142)

Comment: @WReach according to this answer the Functions and API completely changed from v11 to v12, so the server request limit previously relied on an external provider, while it's now Wolfram specific

Comment: There appears to be a daily limit. `BlockchainBlockData[683175, "TransactionList"]` works today.